# How to replace surrounding groups of a match using regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace

I have the following string:

> [Element][TOPINCLUDESAMEVALUES:5][ParentElement][ORDERBY:DateAdded]

and want to transform it to this:

> [Element][TOP:5:WITHTIES][ParentElement][ORDERBY:DateAdded]

So, the `[TOPINCLUDESAMEVALUES:5]` is transform to `[TOP:5:WITHTIES]`.

The input string could contain more `[elements]`. Each element is surrounded by square brackets `[]`. For example:

```
...[element1][element2][TOPINCLUDESAMEVALUES:5]...[element3][element4][TOPINCLUDESAMEVALUES:105][element3]...
```

So, I need to transform each `[TOPINCLUDESAMEVALUES:X]` element to `[TOP:X:WITHTIES]` elements.

Generally, I try some combinations using [regex replace substitutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#substitutions) but was not able to do it myself.

```
 string statement = "[Campaign][TOPINCLUDESAMEVALUES:5][InstanceID][GROUPBY:Campaign]";
 statement = Regex.Replace(statement, @"(?<=\[TOPINCLUDESAMEVALUES:)[^\]]+(?=\])", "");
```

Could anyone tell is there a way to do such replace?

Comment: Not knowing the load of data you'd be evaluating for replacement, but you might want to consider a manual replacement algorithm over regex for performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are replacing the content of `TOPINCLUDESAMEVALUES` with something else, you need to *capture* it. Lookbehind that you are using is *non-capturing*, so you wouldn't be able to replace its content.

Here is how you should be able to do it:

```
statement = Regex.Replace(
    statement
,   @"\[TOPINCLUDESAMEVALUES:([^\]]+)\]", "[TOP:$1:WITHTIES]"
);
```

This expression would match the entire `[TOPINCLUDESAMEVALUES:5]` bracketed portion, and additionally capture `5` as capturing group number 1. The replacement value refers to that group as `$1`, pasting its content in between `TOP:` and `:WITHTIES`.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/SWkiRX)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    string statement = "[Campaign][TOPINCLUDESAMEVALUES:5][InstanceID][GROUPBY:Campaign]";
    string[] arrstatement = "[Campaign][TOPINCLUDESAMEVALUES:5][InstanceID][GROUPBY:Campaign]".Split(']');
    for (int i = 0; i < arrstatement.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arrstatement[i].Contains("TOPINCLUDESAMEVALUES"))
            arrstatement[i] = "[TOP" + arrstatement[i].Substring(arrstatement[i].IndexOf(":")) + ":WITHTIES";
    }
    statement = string.Join("]", arrstatement);
```